# Dividing dictionary into two based on length on string value

Tags: python, string, dictionary, typeerror

I've been working on a function where I need to take the input from three separate groups of tweets and create three new sets based on the whether the list was longer than 50 characters or not. I'm not really sure how to go about this so I've put my last attempt in the code box below.

```
def filter_short_tweets(tweet):

    {i for i in tweet if tweet['text'][i] > 50}
    return tweet

filter_short_tweets(k1_tweets)
```

So far no matter what I do the result I always get it is 
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Any help with this would be very much appreciated.
Thankyou.

Comment: Can you give an example of `k1_tweets`? Also see [mcve].

Comment: What is your line `{i for i in tweet if tweet['text'][i] > 50}` trying to do?

Comment: or `{i for i in tweet if i['text'] > 50}`?

Comment: The `tweet` parameter to your function is probably a (misnamed) `list` of dictionaries.

Comment: You are creating a set using a set comprehension but not assigning it to anything.  You are returning a value from the function but not assigning that to anything either.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def filter_short_tweets(tweets):
    return [tweet for tweet in tweets if len(tweet['text']) > 50]

filter_short_tweets(k1_tweets)
```